# Convexity of the matrix function (Schur Product Operator norm)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, convex-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a function defined as

$$
\mathbf{f(X)} = \min_{~~~~U,V\\\mathbf{X = UV'}} \max_i \mathbf{\|U_i\|} \max_i \mathbf{\|V_i\|} \\  \text{where } \mathbf{U_i} ~\text{and}~ \mathbf{V_i} ~ \text{are row vectors and } \|\cdot\| ~\text{is the}~ \ell_2 ~\text{norm}
$$
$\mathbf{X}$ is a real rectangular matrix of dimension $m \times n$.

How can I prove that the function is convex ?

According to the [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.2093.pdf) , this quantity is the optimum of the Schur product operator norm of a matrix: $f(A) = \max_{X :\|X\|=1} \|A \circ X\|$.

Comment: @harfe, since SVD exists for all matrices, I assume such case will not arise.

Comment: What is V' in the post?

Comment: @HKLee, transpose of V.

Comment: Isn't it the case that $f(X)=\max_{i,j}(|X_{i,j}|)$ ? At least $\geq$ is easy to prove. Unless you have a counterexample, then I'm wrong with the guess.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek, No.  I updated the question with some more details I found.

Comment: Ah, sure. That was too naive. Well at least it will be easy to show convexity from here. All these spectral norm problems reduce to some sdp.

Answer (score 1):

Using the equivalent description that you mentioned, it is easier to show that $f$ is convex.

For a fixed $X$, the function
$$
g_X(A) = \| A \circ X \|
$$
is convex, because $A\mapsto A\circ X$ is linear and norms are convex.

Then,
$$
f(A) = \sup_{X:\|X\|=1} g_X(A)
$$
means that $f$ is the supremum of convex functions and therefore convex itself.